# Angular JS - bind a custom html attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-bind

I'm just starting with Angular JS and i find it very handy in terms of data handling.

My question, is it possible to bind a custom attribute by html alone? Specifically with the select element.

Instead of getting the value attribute, i want to get a custom attribute from the option tags under select element.

Just to be clear, instead of displaying the "value" of the input element, i want to display what's inside the data-custom1 which is the word "payment".

Example would be:

```
<select ng-model="colors">
<option data-color-hex="#2ba2ba" value="1"> Color A<option>
<option data-color-hex="#222222" value="2"> Color B<option>
<option data-color-hex="#cacaca" value="3"> Color X <option>
</select>

<p>{{display the data-color-hex value here}} </p>
```

If i select an option from the select element, the data-color-hex is displayed
in the

element instead of value 1,2,3.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you perhaps provide a more complete example?

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen What i want to do is instead of getting the "value" attribute from the input element, i want to get the value from the data-custom1 attribute which has a value of payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to set a `name` for your `select`:

```
<select name="colors" ng-model="$ctrl.colors">
   <option value="1" data-custom1="paymentA">1</option>
   <option value="2" data-custom1="paymentB">2</option>
   <option value="3" data-custom1="paymentC">3</option>
</select>
```

Then, you can create a method in your `ctrl` which returns the `data-custom1` attribute from the selected option:

```
$ctrl.getDataCustomFromSelect = function(selectName) {
  return document.querySelector('select[name="' + selectName + '"] option:checked')
    .getAttribute('data-custom1');
}
```

You can get that in your template doing:

```
<p ng-bind="$ctrl.getDataCustomFromSelect('colors')"><p>
```

Fiddle with that solution: https://jsfiddle.net/virgilioafonsojr/b002ccja/

I hope I understood your problem correctly and it solves the issue.

Comment: hi i tried to update your fiddle into using select and option but it doesnt work. Can you help? https://jsfiddle.net/t4Lhr385/

Comment: Thanks! I already marked your answer correct. Just a question, isnt possible to achieve it without calling js right?

Comment: It's not possible, you can only access the select value using angular.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this, and you'll probably want to use the first:

```
<input ng-model="amount" data-custom1="{{payment}}">

<p>{{payment}}<p>
```

Or by using ngAttr:

```
<input ng-model="amount" ng-attr-payment="{{payment}}">

<p>{{payment}}<p>
```

The latter one is used for picky DOM APIs like the SVG DOM API. You can read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation

Answer (score 0):

If you want get the input value, **you have to use ng-model**, only this.

And then, in your controller.js, get the input value from ng-model.

(I don't know if that's what you want to know)